# Separating Axis 3d

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I tried to make a SAT 3d test for 2 Tetrahedron.
I made a little Algorithm that works little the following.
But it doesn't really works.

After hours of searching i found this sentence:

> The face normal directions are not enough
>
> You also need to check the directions produced by taking the cross
>   products of the edges, one from each polyhedron

What does this mean?

If i calc the Crossproduct of the 2 sides of each  Tetrahedron, I already have the cross product of the edges.

I don't know what this sentence means, can someone explain it?

Here's a little summaray:

i made this for each Tetrahedron.

I made the face normals with the cross product of two edges, like this:
getcross((PointB-PointA)),(PointC-PointA));
for each face, to get the normal.
then i searched the biggest and smallest Projection value.
then I compered them for overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment means you should take every edge from Tetrahedron1 and take its cross product with every edge from Tetrahedron2 (36 combinations).

When you are calculating face normal, you take both edge from the same tetrahedron.

Comment: so i can take any edge i want from each polyedron?